# The real function of the "GO" Statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I heard that `GO` statement separates the command batches in SQL. And the `CREATE` transaction should be the only query on a batch.

But when i try:

```
Create database dbTest
Create table tbSomething(ID int primary key,Name varchar(30))
GO
```

The output is still SUCCESS.

So how does the `GO` Statement affect the SQL batches?

Comment: Which database system are you using? MySQL? MS SQL Server? Oracle? The `GO` statement is not a standard SQL feature, and its behaviour is probably different in each DBMS.

Comment: "the CREATE transaction " ....CREATE does not start a Transaction. A Transaction is a specific thing in relational databases, don't use that word to mean something else, such as the execution of a single statement. And "should be the only query on a batch." ...should it? Why? Is that a convention you've been told to adhere to? It's not a rule enforced by the DBMS, in my experience. If you want to abide by that convention then you can do so, but the database won't force you.

Comment: @ADyson SQL Server demands a CREATE statement be the first statement in a batch.

Comment: @TT. in which version? I just ran `CREATE TABLE test(test NVARCHAR(10))
CREATE TABLE test2(test2 NVARCHAR(20))
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.test
DROP TABLE dbo.test2
GO` in SQL 2008 and 2016 both with no issues. If create must always be the first statement in the batch then why did that succeed? Surely the second CREATE should fail? (I'm not trying to say you're wrong necessarily, I'm just genuinely interested...maybe I misunderstood)

Comment: @TT. ok, did a bit of googling, apparently it depends what you are creating... see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34654/sql-server-must-be-first-statement-in-query-batch-what-and-why . Creating tables and databases is not restricted by this rule.

Comment: @DezVn Are you talking about Microsoft SQL Server here, or a different database product? Please clarify. The comments I've posted above related to SQL Server specifically.

Comment: And there is nothing magical about "GO". That is just the default. You can change the batch separator to something else. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### **`GO`** is used to divide a script into multiple batches.

The word **`GO`** is not a sql statement. It is understood by the SQL batch processor (for example SSMS) not by SQL Server.

Simply put, if **`GO`** appears on a line on its own, SSMS sends each section delimited by **`GO`** as a separate batch. SQL Server never sees the **`GO`** lines, only the SQL between them.

Because SQL Server has a syntactic rule that stored procedures must be defined in a batch on their own, you will often find database creation scripts which use **`GO`** to delimit the batches so that multiple stored procedures can be created from one script. However it is the client software which understands **`GO`** and divides the batches, not SQL server.

Comment: @DezVn You don't appear to have read the answer. `GO` cannot be used in a stored procedure because it is not a valid SQL command. Your SQL code from the question will work with or without `GO` provided you are executing it from SSMS. If you fire up an ADO connection and sent that code directly, it will *not* work with `GO`.

Answer (score 2):

'GO' statement in SQL server is to just sends a signal to take the current batch of SQL statements for execution.

To tell in simple words, it works like a delimiter.

It is an indication of end of SQL statement [i.e., 1 batch that needs to be executed].

Comment: This answer is wrong. `GO` is [never sent to the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) and is not interpreted by it.